# Computer communicate with sensor directly without microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, microprocessor

I wonder why an USB Webcam can work with minimum design for only 3$, it can send data from CMOS Camera to computer via USB connection and i can't find any additional microcontroller in the board. So it mean no need to using an external microcontroller for manipulating the CMOS sensor ? How it work and how can i do it ?

Edited : 
The image you see is big but the real size is just 3cm square for the board contain 6 led, 1 microphone, 1 quartz, 1 CMOS sensor, a few dozen resistor and capacitor... The biggest chip i found in the center of this board is the CMOS sensor and i don't think i can found any microcontroller here.

[image: Enter description here]

Comment: Why do you think that it doesn't contain a microcontroller  of some sort?

Comment: Hello Ignacio, I've edited my question

Comment: That big chip in the middle, have you investigated what that is? In mass production, devices such as FPGAs are used to eliminate the need for a microcontroller, and provide all the interfacing, signal and data processing, and other functions a microcontroller would be expected to do, and much more, usually faster than a microcontroller can. Often, microcontroller cores are available for implementation within an FPGA.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh I have look on the information write in the chip. It write 'ESP258G', i find in google but found nothing. So i think it's just the CMOS sensor. Ok so now i understand

Comment: The 3$ price is only possibly due to many millions of the same device being produced, often re-badged under various brands.

Answer (score 2):

Now that you've added an image that is an integrated circuit (IC) not a CMOS image sensor. They are often referred to as image processors and typically contain a microcontroller, USB interface, camera interface and some logic to assist with image compression. An example datasheet is the [OV519 CameraMate Processor](https://web.archive.org/web/20170216231430/http://www.comedia.com.cn/OV%20SENSOR%20PB/controllor/OV519%20Datasheet%20_v1.3.pdf) but there are many types.

They are made for this specific application. You may be able to read the part number for the device used by that particular camera, or it may be an ASIC manufactured for that company that doesn't have a standard part number. In my experience many of those chips can be hard to source in small quantities as many manufacturers are only interested in orders for hundreds of thousands, at which point no doubt they would cost under a dollar.

Answer (score -4):

Why to use additional microcontroller when the signal processing can be done by CPU of your computer itself?  Signal coming from CMOS sensor is manipulated by your Webcam driver program running inside your operating system.
Microcontroller can be used if you intend to develop some standalone system. In that case, you'll have to write your own driver program for your microcontroller.

Comment: Of course i think so but i need more details. How to do it, any example, open source, circuit ....

Comment: Please point out any webcam which sends CMOS captured signals directly back to the computer, for instance over a USB cable. Also, please explain how the USB negotiation occurs between host and device, even before CMOS data can be transferred?

Comment: Just a heads-up, Vinit: This site can be pretty harsh to people who post invalid, unsubstantiated and outright speculative answers to questions. Please review this and your other posts in this light. This isn't a *forum* where opinions are all that matter, it is a technical question and answer site.